# If Date < Ref Date change Date

Tags: vba

I have a "work date" column (B) which displays dates down the sheet, and a "start date" cell (V7).
I'm trying to figure out how to get column (B)'s work date to change to the value in cell (V7) if the work date is < (v7)

[image: Image of WorkBook]

UPDATE : I have since given a try at putting something together within VBA. Please note I have only been learning VBA for like 2 weeks. The code is currently just inputting whatever date I set within the InputBox down the column instead of only hitting the dates that are < startdate. Please see code and screenshot.

```
Sub Workdatechange()

Dim gpWorkDate As Worksheet
Set gpWorkDate = Worksheets("START")
Dim startdate As Variant
startdate = InputBox("What's the first day of the billing period?")
Dim lRow As Integer

With gpWorkDate

    lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    
    For cell = 8 To lRow

        If .Cells(cell, 2).Value >= startdate Then
    
        Else: .Cells(cell, 2).Value = startdate
    
        End If
Next cell
End With
End Sub
```

[image: Current Output]

Comment: You don't need VBA for this. In cell V8 enter the formula `=MAX(B8,V$7)`. Copy that formula down column V

Comment: I need it to replace the values within column B, I'm exporting this data to SQL...

Comment: Once values are calculated in column V, copy them and paste special the values in column B. Then delete column V

Comment: Reason for using vba and connecting the code to a button is for ease of use. Since this will happen multiple times a day, getting away from copying and pasting is why VBA will be useful. Otherwise I could just sort from smallest to largest and copy paste the data in quickly.

Comment: In that case please update your post with vba code you have already tried highlighting the area(s) that you're having problems with. If you don't have code yet, a good place to start is to start the macro recorder and follow all the steps I mentioned above. Add the formula in V8, copy down the column, copy and paste special values into column B and finally delete formulas from column V. update your post with that code and someone can help you make it more dynamic.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```vb
Sub Workdatechange()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim lDatesCol As Long: lDatesCol = 2
    Dim lRows As Long
    Dim lStartRow As Long: lStartRow = 8
    Dim lEmptyCol As Long
    Dim rngDates As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("START")
        lEmptyCol = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column + 1
        lRows = .Cells(Rows.Count, lDatesCol).End(xlUp).Row - lStartRow + 1
        Set rngDates = .Cells(lStartRow, lDatesCol).Resize(lRows, 1)
        With .Cells(lStartRow, lEmptyCol).Resize(lRows, 1)
            .Formula2 = "=MAX(B" & lStartRow & ",V$7)"
            rngDates.Value2 = .Value2
            .ClearContents
        End With
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Two reason I chose the formula approach: 1. it is fast and 2. to avoid having to deals with some subtle internationalisation issues when exchanging dates between excel and vba, which varies across different versions.